# MySQL COUNT from multiple tables with group

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to find 2 results from the `disciplines` table below. The first COUNT would be to see how many Certificates are assigned to each discipline by using the `disciplines_certificates` table. The second COUNT would be to see how many Workers have the discipline assigned `workers_disciplines`

I have managed to do individual queries to fetch these answers, but I'm not sure what I need to do in order to get both results in 1 query. (I've just copied over the results with an actual answer to save space, but the end result should include all disciplines.

Query to select the used certificates

```
SELECT `disciplines`.* , COUNT(disciplines_certificates.certificate_id) as used_certificates
FROM (`disciplines`)
LEFT JOIN `disciplines_certificates` ON `disciplines_certificates`.`discipline_id` = `disciplines`.`id`
GROUP BY `disciplines`.`id`
```

Result:

```
+----+-------------------------+-------------------+
| id |         discipline_name | used_certificates |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------+
| 10 |        Crane Op Level 3 |                 3 |
| 18 |        Appointed Person |                 2 |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

Query to select the used disciplines

```
SELECT `disciplines`.*, COUNT(workers_disciplines.discipline_id) as used_disciplines
FROM (`disciplines`)
LEFT JOIN `workers_disciplines` ON `workers_disciplines`.`discipline_id` = `disciplines`.`id`
GROUP BY `disciplines`.`id`
```

Result:

```
+----+-------------------------+------------------+
| id |         discipline_name | used_disciplines |
+----+-------------------------+------------------+
| 10 |        Crane Op Level 3 |                1 |
+----+-------------------------+------------------+
```

Query I tried to use to select all data:

```
SELECT `disciplines`.*, COUNT(disciplines_certificates.certificate_id) as used_certificates, COUNT(workers_disciplines.discipline_id) as used_disciplines
FROM (`disciplines`)
LEFT JOIN `disciplines_certificates` ON `disciplines_certificates`.`discipline_id` = `disciplines`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `workers_disciplines` ON `workers_disciplines`.`discipline_id` = `disciplines`.`id`
GROUP BY `disciplines`.`id`
```

Expected Result:

```
+----+-------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| id |         discipline_name | used_certificates | used_disciplines |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| 10 |        Crane Op Level 3 |                 3 |                1 |
| 18 |        Appointed Person |                 2 |                0 |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Actual Result:

```
+----+-------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| id |         discipline_name | used_certificates | used_disciplines |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| 10 |        Crane Op Level 3 |                 3 |                3 |
| 18 |        Appointed Person |                 2 |                0 |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

You can find the SQLfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/392c4/3

Table `disciplines`

```
+----+-------------------------+
| id |         discipline_name |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 |              Pipefitter |
|  2 |         Inst Pipefitter |
|  3 |                  Plater |
| 10 |        Crane Op Level 3 |
| 18 |        Appointed Person |
+----+-------------------------+
```

Table `disciplines_certificates`

```
+---------------+----------------+
| discipline_id | certificate_id |
+---------------+----------------+
|            10 |              6 |
|            10 |             15 |
|            10 |             20 |
|            18 |              6 |
|            18 |             15 |
+---------------+----------------+
```

Table `workers_disciplines`

```
+-----------|---------------+
| worker_id | discipline_id |
+-----------|---------------+
|         1 |            10 |
+-----------|---------------+
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DISTINCT statement to count only distinct ids.

```
    SELECT `disciplines`.*, 
           COUNT(DISTINCT disciplines_certificates.certificate_id) AS used_certificates, 
           COUNT(DISTINCT workers_disciplines.discipline_id) AS used_disciplines
      FROM `disciplines`
 LEFT JOIN `disciplines_certificates` ON `disciplines_certificates`.`discipline_id` = `disciplines`.`id`
 LEFT JOIN `workers_disciplines` ON `workers_disciplines`.`discipline_id` = `disciplines`.`id`
  GROUP BY `disciplines`.`id`
```

Comment: Didn't realise I was so close! I had to change COUNT(DISTINCT workers_disciplines.discipline_id) to COUNT(DISTINCT workers_disciplines.worker_id) as with more data it wasn't returning the correct used_disciplines.